# Оптимизация кода по обращению к памяти

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, оптимизация, память

Необходимо написать оптимальную по обращению к памяти функцию для обрезки пробелов справа. Сама обрезка сложностей не вызывает, непонятно, что можно сделать для оптимизации и можно ли вообще оптимизировать такую реализацию.

```
void TrimRight(char* s) {
size_t len = strlen(s);
char* iter = s + len - 1;
if (*iter != ' ') {
    // Если последний символ не пробел, 
    // то и обрезать нечего
    return;
}
while (*iter == ' ' && iter != s) {
    // Идти от конца к началу, 
    // пока не кончатся пробелы либо строка
    iter--;
}
if (iter == s) {
    // Если строка пройдена
    // и полностью состоит из пробелов
    // то результатом будет пустая строка
    *iter = '\0';
}
else {
    // Если пройдены все пробелы 
    // и поиск дошел до первого не пробела,
    // то заменить первый пробел на конец строки.
    *(iter + 1) = '\0';
}

}
```

Comment: Ну разве что (если это что-то даст) - идти с начала до конца, встретив пробел, запоминать позицию и идти дальше. Если до конца строки одни пробелы - всадить на запомненное место 0. Если встречается не пробел - сброс запомненного места и идти дальше... Просто чтоб не сканировать строку в поисках конца в вызове `strlen`. Что даст лучшие результаты - не уверен, надо экспериментировать...

Comment: Возможно (только возможно, а не факт!), что сэкономите ещё пару тактов за вызов,  если в if-then-else в `then` опишете более вероятный вариант, а в `else` — менее вероятный.

Comment: Максимальное ускорение получится, если просматривать не по байту, а сразу по слову, размером `size_t` (естественно, выровненному). (детали нужны или сами попробуете?)

Comment: @avp Не откажусь от деталей.

Comment: @SergeyU, детали в ответе

Comment: @avp Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/EwHSCG

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char *trimRight(char *s)
{
  char *spc=0, *p=s;

  while (*p)
    if (*p == ' ')
      for (spc=p; *++p==' '; );
    else
      ++p;

  if (spc && p!=s && p[-1]==' ') *spc = 0;

  return s;
}

int main()
{
  char s[256];

  cout << '"' << trimRight(strcpy(s, ""))                  << '"' << endl;
  cout << '"' << trimRight(strcpy(s, "abc qwe zzz   "))    << '"' << endl;
  cout << '"' << trimRight(strcpy(s, "abc  qwe  zzz   "))  << '"' << endl;
  cout << '"' << trimRight(strcpy(s, "abc  qwe  zzz   u")) << '"' << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Согласен, этот вариант работает быстрее. Свой ответ удалил.

Comment: @Harry, быстрее твоего или авторского?

Comment: Авторского. И, понятно, моего :) Проверял на длинных строках с большими количествами пробелов.

Comment: @Harry, ну мало ли. А то вдруг strlen быстрее этого цикла?)) По идее, на строках, где примерно половина пробелов (т. е. через один, а не подряд), но последний не пробел авторский окажется быстрее.

Comment: На строках покороче - увы, отстает... https://ideone.com/t5YvS3

Comment: @Harry, странно. По идее длина строк не должна влиять же?

Comment: Первая ссылка - для строки 40 мегабайт, эта - https://ideone.com/jpikfl - для гигабайтной :) Или какие-то не отловленные мной ошибки и непонятки...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100423/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-harry).

Comment: @Qwertiy Действительно, ваш вариант работает примерно вдвое быстрее моего. Я правильно понял, что оптимизация достигнута за счет того, что на каждой итерации цикла происходит только одно стравнение и нет сравнения с началом строки? И это же компенсирует проигрышь от того, что проходится вся строка, а не только конец, как у меня.

Comment: @SergeyU, у тебя тоже проходится вся строка - только внутри strlen. А потом ты по хвосту проходишь второй раз в обратном направлении. В чате есть ещё ссылки на замеры скорости, но почему один из вариантов предпочтительнее, я не понял. По идее, для моего кода худший случай - когда пробелы чередуются с непробелами. Для твоего - когда вся строка состоит из пробелов. Что будет лучше в реальности - понятия не имею.

Comment: Для `__GNUC__` [strlen](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/strlen.c) однозначно быстрей

Comment: @Harry `3*N/4` будет целочисленное переполнение при гигабайте.

Comment: @VTT Мда, второй прокол за вчерашний вечер на этой задаче... Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный вариант - поиск последнего не пробельного символа для уменьшения количества сравнений:

```
void Trim_Naive(char * p_char)
{
    auto p_begin_or_last_non_ws{p_char};
    for(;;)
    {
        switch(*p_char)
        {
            case '\0':
            {
                break;
            }
            case ' ':
            {
                ++p_char;
                continue;
            }
            default:
            {
                p_begin_or_last_non_ws = p_char;
                ++p_char;
                continue;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    if(' ' == *p_begin_or_last_non_ws)
    {
        p_begin_or_last_non_ws[0] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        p_begin_or_last_non_ws[1] = '\0';
    }
    return;
}
```

[Поглядим на производительность.](https://ideone.com/ZUBQiw):

```
chars count = 64000000
trailing spaces_percent = 1
spaces percent = 20
strlen 63999999 3342
strlen naive 63999999 21940
OP    3321
Q     136068
naive 27858

chars count = 64000000
trailing spaces_percent = 50
spaces percent = 20
strlen 63999999 3105
strlen naive 63999999 22620
OP    20668
Q     77093
naive 27658

chars count = 64000000
trailing spaces_percent = 99
spaces percent = 20
strlen 63999999 3064
strlen naive 63999999 22692
OP    41996
Q     20818
naive 24656
```

Выводы:

1. Библиотечный `strlen` оптимизирован и работает в разы быстрее наивной реализации.
2. Итерация по массиву в обратную сторону медленнее.
3. В реалистичной ситуации, когда сравнительно длинная строка оканчивается сравнительно небольшим количеством пробелов, код из вопроса работает отлично. Когда непробельные символы встречаются только в начале строки, он несколько деградирует.
4. Вариант из ответа Qwertiy наоборот, в реалистичной ситуации работает очень плохо, и достигает приемлемой производительности когда непробельные символы встречаются только в начале.
5. Вариант с наивной реализацией из этого ответа показывает приемлемую производительность независимо от содержимого строки.

Comment: Интересно, но я не понимаю, как так получилось. Я не вижу принципиальной разницы между моим и твоим кодом, но как-то оказывается, что твой быстрее. К тому же, у меня вроде делается около двух сравнений каждого символа строки, а значит время должно быть в 2 раза хуже чем у StrlenNaive и примерно такое же как у Trim_Naive. Но на практике оказывается совершенно не так - из-за чего?

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня используется `switch`, причем `default` заканчивается кодом, аналогичным `case ' '`. [ассемблер самый простой и короткий](https://godbolt.org/z/N4_pBl) Если делать то же самое через `if`, то получается [менее эффективно](https://godbolt.org/z/v2jbpU) У твоего варианта инструкций [в два раза больше](https://godbolt.org/z/YIEfIl), когда в строке сплош пробелы он не вылезает из `*++p==' '`, а в других ситуациях видимо переключения между разными циклами приводят к потере эффективности.

Comment: Что-то он недооптимизировал ((( Мог бы и получше пожать, до твоего варианта :)

Comment: Я вот что-то такое ожидал: https://ideone.com/azkyfQ - поможешь исправить чтобы компилировалось?

Comment: А, сам понял...

Comment: Блин.. Что-то не то. Godbolt [скомпилил](https://godbolt.org/z/qjnJf3), а ideone [куча всего не нравится](https://ideone.com/sYpUOD).

Comment: Компилятор не тот. Нашёл, где запустить и пофиксил пару багов, но оно всё равно не работает: https://wandbox.org/permlink/VTUXz2GrLK5F5OuL

Comment: Ага, проблему понял, как исправить не знаю: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1040307/178988

Answer (score 1):

По возможности сравниваем с пробелом не по байту, а целыми словами

```
// trim tail spaces from `char str[]`
// return str
//   and it's new length in second argument
char *
trim2 (char str[], size_t *len)
{
  size_t dummy;
  if (!len)
    len = &dummy;
  char *t = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  size_t mask = sizeof(char *) - 1,
    blank = (sizeof(char *) == 4) ? 0x20202020 : 0x2020202020202020ULL;

  while (t >= str) {
    if (*t != ' ')
      return t[1] = 0, *len = t - str + 1, str;

    if (((size_t)t & mask) == 0 && t - str > mask) {
      // the address is aligned and the length is sufficient 
      // compare by words
      size_t *p = (size_t *)(t - (mask + 1));
      while (p >= (size_t *)str) {
    if (*p != blank) 
      break;  // somewhere in this word there is no space
    p--;
      }

      // again compare each byte
      t = (char *)p + mask;
      continue;
    }
    t--;
  }

  // empty 
  return *str = 0, *len = 0, str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
void TrimRight(char* s) {
  char* space = null;  // Изначально пробелов нет
  // цикл до конца строки
  while (*s != '\0') {
    if (*s == ' ') {  // если нашли пробел
      // и до этого пробелов не было
      if (space == null)
        space = s;  // запомнили позицию
    } else  // если нашли не пробел
      space = null;  // забыли, что видели пробел
    s++;
  }
  // если таки нашли пробел
  if (space != null)
    *space = '\0';  // обрезали строку
}
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, от моего способа отличается одним - бесконечной работой... :)

Comment: @Harry Еще буковки другие :). Исправил